# Meteor/Jade: Use variable in template ID

Tags: templates, meteor, pug

How can I use a variable like `{{_id}}` within a template id tag? It renders as text inside the tag instead of part of the ID name.

Template:

```
div.element-versions#element_{{name}} // "name" evaluates to "001_version"
```

Renders as:

```
<div class="element-versions" id="element_">001_version</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="element-versions" id="element_001_version"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.element-versions(id='element_{{name}}')
```

Where 'name' can be a helper or a field of the current data context. Jade defaults to using divs, so you can leave off 'div' from your element tag as well if you want to.

Comment: Of course. I knew I was forgetting something obvious. Thanks, looshi! Final code: `div(id="element_{{name}}").element-versions`